# height % not working and images in a function

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 small? questions

First off im unable to get my slider divs (slider, left, links and toggle) to 100% of window height i can make a new div at 1005 but these four wont listen.

Second, how would i go about changing 'close' and 'open' to images in my slider function, i tried just replacing them with the img html but it just spits out the text.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgRAs/

css:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #d4d1ce;
    top: 0px;
}
#logo { 
    height: 109px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
.slider {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    background: url(left.png);
}
.links {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #1e1c1b;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.toggle {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(toggle.png);
}
```

body:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.links').hide();
        $('.toggle').click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $(this).siblings('.links').slideToggle(200, function () {
                $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'close' : 'open');
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<div id='container'>

    <div id='logo'>
        <img src='logo.png'>
    </div>

    <div id='content'>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="links">Links here</div>
    <div class="toggle"><img src='slider_open.png'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgRAs/

Comment: improvement: first change the text to close then open the links bar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
Display: table;
```

on .slider and in order to inject html with jquery you need to use

```
$(this).html("...");
```

instead of .text.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/7cW3M/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` instead of table-cell positioning. Set 100% height to #logo. jQuery has a toggle() function to show/hide divs easily. [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.links').hide();
        $('.toggle').click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $(this).siblings('.links').slideToggle(200, function () {
                $this.html($(this).is(':visible') ? "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png' />" : "<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg' />");
            });

        });
    });
```

I have changed your text() to html() and that worked with the image tags. You just need to set your initial html to show whatever link you want.

Here's my version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgRAs/3/